# SQL Efficient way to locate an example of each combination

Tags: sql, sybase

Is there a more efficient way of querying a table (or collection of table) for all possible combinations of a few columns, I'm currently running group by and then max, but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way.

SQL Fiddle for the below example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25f8b/3

Example Table

```
ID | Name | Age | City   | Color
--------------------------------
1  | Dave | 10  | London | Red
2  | Dave | 11  | London | Purple
3  | Dave | 10  | Paris  | Orange
4  | Jim  | 10  | London | Red
5  | Jim  | 10  | London | Green
6  | Jim  | 11  | London | Lazer
etc... (around 500,000 rows)
```

Currently doing:

```
SELECT  max(ID), Name, Age, City, Color
from People
group by Name, Age, City
```

To produce:

```
MAX(ID) NAME    AGE CITY    COLOR
1       Dave    10  London  Red
3       Dave    10  Paris   Orange
2       Dave    11  London  Purple
5       Jim     10  London  Red
6       Jim     11  London  Lazer
```

- Note 4 is missing as it's a exact duplicate of 5
- 3 Is included as it has a different city to 1, even with same age/name

However currently on this massive database it takes around a ten minutes to return the results (note it's actually a join of a few tables)

Is there a more efficient way to return the same results? I was imagining a mass collection of `SELECT * WHERE name = %, age = % and city = % LIMIT 1` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

To get the different combinations there is as reserved word `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Age, City
FROM People
```

This gives the same result as :

```
SELECT Name, Age, City
FROM People
GROUP BY Name, Age, City
```

However it is limited :

- If you add a column (like Color), it is included in the combinations analysis
- You can't use aggregate functions, like MAX
- I don't know if it's any better performance wise

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use distinct for reason #1, I need the ID's of the rows, otherwise the information isn't really of use to me!